# Writing another function inside of script that's formatting a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

So I have some pre-existing code that has a table being formatted inside a script with JSON and a function:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script>

View Jobs on dashboard
function getJobs(){
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var txt = "<table style='width:100%;'>";    
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (x in myObj) {
            var status = myObj[x].job_status;
            var job_type = myObj[x].job_type;
            var jobColor;
            if(status == "Complete"){
                jobColor = "red";
            } else {
                jobColor = "green";
            }
```

This is the function I'm trying to add:

```
function toggle_visibility(jobID) {
    const billingTicket = document.getElementById("billingticket" + jobID);
    const style = (billingTicket.style.display === "none") ? "inline-block" : "none";

    billingTicket.style.display = style;
    document.getElementById("billing_status" + jobID).style.display = style;
    document.getElementById("lease_name" + jobID).style.display = style;
    document.getElementById("drilling_contractor" + jobID).style.display = style;
}
```

As you can see, I've already modified the code below and changed the ID's

```
            txt += "<tr>";
            txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].job_date + "</td>";
            txt += "<td onclick='toggle_visibility(job_id)'><a href='get-job.php?job=" + myObj[x].job_id + "' target='_blank'>" + myObj[x].job_id + "</a></td>";
            txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].billing_ticket_id + "</td>";
            txt += "<td id = 'drilling_contractor5'>" + myObj[x].drilling_contractor + "</td>";
            txt += "<td id = 'company_name5'>" + myObj[x].company + "</td>";
            txt += "<td id = 'lease_name5'>" + myObj[x].lease_name + "</td>";
            txt += "<td style='color: " + jobColor + ";'>" + myObj[x].job_status + "</td>";
            txt += "</tr>";

        }
        txt += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = txt;
    } 
    //document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;

};
  xhttp.open("POST", "get-jobs.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send();
}

getJobs();
```

Those 4 code sections above make up the entirety of my code.

I understand that perhaps the function isn't able to reference the table, if this is so. Why not? And how would I get this to work?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: a little more detail might help, like the json. Some error messages, or results of things you've tried already.

Comment: The error message is usually this: Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_visibility is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick.

Or: toggle_visibility(job_id) is undefined.

As for the JSON, I believe it's being used to retrieve data from another place on the server.

Comment: Is the `toggle_visibility()` function defined at top-level? Code executed from `onclick` is in the global scope.

Comment: Can you post the whole code instead of separate pieces?

Comment: This is all of it.